# Multiple routes defined getting 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

The first route created by laravel works fine but the second I created does not work

**localhost/myapp/public/** works very well

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

but **localhost/myapp/public/hello** doesn't work  browser shows message sorry the page your looking for could not be found

```
Route::get('/hello', function () {
    return "Hello world";
});
```

Comment: run `php artisan serve` inside ` localhost/myapp`

Comment: What webserver are you using? Does it have URL rewriting enabled?

Comment: thank you very much C2486 it has worked

Comment: php artisan serve makes it work fine using xampp

Answer (score 0):

remove '/'
use

```
Route::get('hello', function () {
return "Hello world"; });
```